# Fetch folder and sub folders name and files full path in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

how can the name of a folder and names of all the sub folders within that folder be fetched.

For example if we upload a file and as say

`$file->getClientOriginalName();`

and it gets the name of the file as it is stored in the device similarly

Is there any method which returns the full directory of the folder or the path of files stored within that folder?

Comment: i am building an application where a huge data is to be seeded into the database where the names of the main folders are the cities and the sub folders are the companies and files are the office locations. So i need a seeder which can read the name of the main folders are put it the cites column in the database and so on.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/filesystem#directories